# Permutation of n symbols

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> For n ≥ 1, let $S_n$ denote the group of all permutations on n symbols.
>   Which of the following statements is true ?
>
> A. S3 has an element of order 4
>
> B. S4 has an element of order 6
>
> C. S4 has an element of order 5
>
> D. S5 has an element of order 6.

My work:
Order of group is $n!$.

A and C are false (by Lagrange theorem).
Now how can i proceed next intuitively ?

Comment: Have a gander at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function

Comment: An unenlightening approach is to make the assumption that the problem has just one answer and then to note that if B is true, then so is D since $S_4$ is a subgroup of $S_5$. Thus, only D is true. *More seriously*, what do you know about permutations? Specifically, are you aware of how to determine the order of a given permutation?

Comment: Ya i know order of elemet in permutation group

Comment: I think landau function helps

Comment: The order of an element is the least common multiple of the orders of its cycle lengths. When evaluating if B is false, try to choose the cycle lengths of a permutation whose lcm is 6. You will find that this is impossible for several numbers whose sum is 4.

Comment: @Mike Earnest thanks ,actually i forgot this .you may post this as answer if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question B**

An element of $\mathcal S_4$ is either a $2$-cycle (of order $2$), a $3$-cycle (having order $3$), a product of two $2$-cycles (having order $2$) or a $4$-cycle (of order $4$). Hence none of the elements of $\mathcal S_4$ may have order $6$.

**Question D**

A product of two disjoint cycles of order $2$ and $3$ has indeed order $6$ in $\mathcal S_5$. This is the case for example of $(1 \ 2 \ 3)(4 \ 5)$.

Comment: Is there any general way to look at this tyoe of question

Comment: Your answer is illuminating

Comment: The permutation given by disjoint (disjoint is important) cycles $\sigma_i$ is given by the $\text{l.c.d.}\{\sigma_i\}$.  This is a good exercise to check.

Comment: @CloudJR Any permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. So looking at disjoint cycles is often useful! Also because cycles ar simple to study.

Comment: L.c.d? Liquid crystal display? lol...do you mean l.c.m.?

Comment: Sorry, i just say this for fun